# Sum of prime numbers below 1 million?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the sum of all prime numbers below 1 million but my code takes a lot of time. Any other method to execute the code faster?

```
b=1
d = 0
#generates a list of numbers.
while b<1000000:
    b=b+1
    x = 0.0
    a = 0
    #generates a list of numbers less than b. 
    while x<b:
        x=x+1
        #this will check for divisors. 
        if (b/x)-int(b/x) == 0.0:
            a=a+1
    if a==2:
        #if it finds a prime it will add it.
        d=d+b
print(d)
```

Comment: This is more a math issue than a python one. Read more about [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)s and [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). But notice that StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* service. Consider *keeping* the prime numbers that you already know and use them later (to determine if some number is prime)

Comment: even numbers after 2 are not prime.

Comment: Have an array from 1 to 1,000,000,000. Then using [Seive's algorithm], remove elements of 2,4,6,8, and then 3,6,9,12, and then 5,10,15,20 and finally `sum` the remaining elements in the array. 

    [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try this simple code it's very faster than yours :)

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
   if n == 1:
      return False
   if n == 2:
      return True
   if n > 2 and n % 2 ==0:
      return False

   max_divisor = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
   for d in range(3, 1 + max_divisor,2):
     if n % d ==0:
        return False
   return True

primes = [x for x in range(1,1000000) if isPrime(x) ==True]
print(sum(primes))
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `n > 2` check (just the `n % 2 == 0` one) as you already checked for 1 and 2 (and I assume n will not be 0 or lower)

Answer (score 1):

[Primality Test - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

> The simplest primality test is trial division: Given an input number
>   n, check whether any prime integer m from 2 to √n evenly divides n

I would start by defining a function that simply checks if a number is prime or not. Then use that function in a loop that counts from 3, 5, 7, 9, ... , 999.999 and check if each number is prime, if it matches then add it to a sum variable.

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(num):
    # According to trial division we only need to check from 2 -> sqrt(num)
    for x in range(2, int(sqrt(num) + 1)):
        if num % x == 0:
             return False
    return True

sum = 2 # Start with 2 in sum because we skip it to make life easier
for x in range(3, 1000000, 2): # Don't bother checking even numbers
    if is_prime(x):
        sum += x
print("Sum: " + str(sum))
```

On my machine this takes about 10 seconds to find an answer which is quite a bit better than your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a very basic and quite fast primality test algorithm.

The following implementation takes about 400ms on a modern machine but it could probably be optimized further.

```
limit = 1000000
is_prime = [x % 2 for x in range(limit)]
is_prime[1] = False
is_prime[2] = True
for candidate in range(3, limit, 2):
    if is_prime[candidate]:
        for product in range(candidate * 3, limit, candidate * 2):
            is_prime[product] = False
print(sum(x for x in range(limit) if is_prime[x]))
```